# Can I connect multiple jenkins projects to same maven repository

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

First Jenkins project:
I have maven project (multiple modules) that create war and jars.
When I'm running `mvn install -DskipTests` it's created those files as expected.

Second Jenkins project:
I want to use the same project/pom (First Jenkins project), use created jars to run `mvn test`.

but from the second project I'm getting compilation errors because jars does not exist.

Should I run under one project ? but how ?

Or how can I get jar from first project into second project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure Maven Repository to be "default" (`~/.m2`) or "Local to executor", otherwise each job makes it's own copy of Maven Repo.